# What is the Pythonic way to apply a function to multi-index multi-columns dataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Given a multi-index multi-column dataframe below, I want to apply LinearRegression to each block of this dataframe, for example, "index(X,1),  column A". And compute the predicted dataframe as df_result.

```
                           A    B
X   1   1997-01-31  -0.061332   0.630682
        1997-02-28  -2.671818   0.377036
        1997-03-31  0.861159    0.303689
        ...
        1998-01-31  0.535192    -0.076420
        ...
        1998-12-31  1.430995    -0.763758
Y   1   1997-01-31  -0.061332   0.630682
        1997-02-28  -2.671818   0.377036
        1997-03-31  0.861159    0.303689
        ...
        1998-01-31  0.535192    -0.076420
        ...
        1998-12-31  1.430995    -0.763758
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

N = 24
dates = pd.date_range('19970101', periods=N, freq='M')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),2),index=dates,columns=list('AB')) 
df2=pd.concat([df,df],keys=[('X','1'),('Y','1')])

regr = LinearRegression()

# df_result will be reassined, copy the index and metadata from df2
df_result=df2.copy()

# I know the double loop below is not a clever idea. What is the right way?
for row in df2.index.to_series().unique():
    for col in df2.columns:
        #df2 can contain missing values
        lenX=np.count_nonzero(df2.ix[row[:1],col].notnull().values.ravel())
        X=np.array(range(lenX)).reshape(lenX,1)
        y=df2.ix[row[:1],col]
        y=y[y.notnull()]

        # train the model
        regr.fit(X,y)

        df_result.ix[row[:1],col][:lenX] = regr.predict(X)
```

The question is that the double loop above make the computing quite slow, more than ten minutes for 100kb data set. What is the pythonic way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The second question for the last line of the code above is that I am working with a copy of a slice of the dataframe. Some columns of "df_result" are not updated with this operation.

**EDIT2:**

Some columns of the original data can contain missing value, and we cannot apply regression directly on them. For example,

```
df2.ix[('X','1','1997-12-31')]['A']=np.nan
df2.ix[('Y','1','1998-12-31')]['A']=np.nan
```

Comment: So you want to perform linear regression at level 0 correct? so all rows for X or all rows at level 1 so each group at that level?

Comment: @EdChum I want to perform LR on level (0,1) on each column, and the date range is always from 1997-01-31 to 1998-12-31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand the row looping.

anyhow, to maintain consistency in the numbers I put `np.random.seed(1)` at the top

In short I think you can achieve what you want with a function, groupby, and call to .transform().

```
def do_regression(y):
    X=np.array(range(len(y))).reshape(len(y),1)
    regr.fit(X,y)
    return regr.predict(X)

df_regressed = df2.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(do_regression)

print df_regressed.head()

                       A         B
X 1 1997-01-31  0.779476 -1.222119
    1997-02-28  0.727184 -1.138630
    1997-03-31  0.674892 -1.055142
    1997-04-30  0.622601 -0.971653
    1997-05-31  0.570309 -0.888164
```

which matches your df_result output.

```
print df_result.head()

                       A         B
X 1 1997-01-31  0.779476 -1.222119
    1997-02-28  0.727184 -1.138630
    1997-03-31  0.674892 -1.055142
    1997-04-30  0.622601 -0.971653
    1997-05-31  0.570309 -0.888164
```

oh and a couple of alternatives for:

```
X=np.array(range(len(y))).reshape(len(y),1)

1.) X = np.expand_dims(range(len(y)), axis=1)
2.) X = np.arange(len(y))[:,np.newaxis]
```

## Edit for empty data

ok 2 suggestions:

Would it be legitimate to use the interpolate method to fill the null values?

```
df2 = df2.interpolate()
```

OR

do the regression on non null values and then pop the nulls back in at the appropriate index position

```
   def do_regression(y):

        x_s =np.arange(len(y))
        x_s_non_nulls =  x_s[y.notnull().values]
        x_s_non_nulls = np.expand_dims(x_s_non_nulls, axis=1)

        y_non_nulls = y[y.notnull()]  # get the non nulls

        regr.fit(x_s_non_nulls,y_non_nulls)  # regression
        results = regr.predict(x_s_non_nulls)

        #pop back in then nulls.
        for idx in np.where(y.isnull().values ==True):
            results = np.insert(results,idx,np.NaN)

        return results
```

Comment: One further question is that some columns contain missing values, namely y in do_regression(y), and regr.fit(X,y) raised "NAN" error. That's why I used notnull() and lenX in my original question. The transform function seems work in a all column same index way, but not column by column. Any further tips?

Comment: Hi Rex, I'm a little unclear, can you post some more information / sample data?